# Migrate yarn.lock dependencies to bun.lockb file

Tags: yarnpkg, bun

I want to read yarn.lock file and generate bun.lockb from that with the same dependencies to be used in `bun install`, without this bun is creating the deps based on package.json and is big projects (specially typescript projects) it brings lost of type conflicts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bun (since version [1.0.5](https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/releases/tag/bun-v1.0.5)) supports migrating `package-lock.json` to `bun.lockb` as seen in [this pull request](https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/pull/6352). However, the support for migrating `yarn.lock` is not implemented yet. You can track the progress on [this issue](https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/issues/6409).

As an intermediate step, we can use [`synp`](https://github.com/imsnif/synp), a tool that converts `yarn.lock` to `package-lock.json`.

Here's the detailed steps:

```bash
# convert yarn.lock to package-lock.json using synp
npx synp --source-file yarn.lock

# upgrade package-lock.json to version 3 using npm
npm i --lockfile-version 3 --frozen-lockfile

# convert package-lock.json to bun.lockb using bun
bun pm migrate
```

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a way to do this yet, but there is an open GitHub issue for it, so maybe soon: https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/issues/1751